# Offline WebApp for iPad

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ipad, offline

I currently work on an open source e-commerce platform (www.oscmax.com) and I am trying to work out if I can deploy an offline version that can run on an iPad.

I can not seem to find an iPad AMP (Apache MySQL PHP) application and was wondering if anyone could answer:

a) Does anyone know of an AMP version that will run on an iPad
b) Is there another way to achieve this without recoding the entire application in XCode.

The idea is to have a local version of the online store that sales reps can use when selling to wholesale customers that will store the orders locally until they find a WiFi or 3G signal.

If I could get Apache, MySQL and PHP to run locally (like it does using WAMP, MAMP, LAMP, etc.) it would be great.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can't run server specific software on an iPad, think of it as a big phone, it just won't do it.  The overhead required for mysql / php / apache to run is not something you want on a client side anyway.  You need to re-do your app. Simple as that.

Comment: Technically, there's no problem. And why should I think of it as a phone? When I first started with web dev, win2k/apache/mysql/php ran just fine on my modest 266 MHz, 96 MB second hand laptop. The iPad is substantially faster an that.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS developer terms prohibit the use of interpreted code in native apps which would rule out running PHP through an iOS app. Your best bet would be to look into HTML5 technologies such as offline storage and build a web app.

Comment: can you please post the source link of this info

Comment: Interpreters are now allowed.  There are currently 5 or more Basic interpreters in the App store.  Downloading code to interpreters is still not allowed.

Comment: Regardless of how easy it would be to run PHP/MySQL on the iPhone it seems the wrong solutions to the problem. The Apple developer site has loads of good resources for developing on mobile Safari. The off line storage features would allow for caching data while off line and synchronising with the server later on.

Answer (score 0):

iOS prohibits apps from spawning processes, and the standard AMP tools spawn lots of processes.  So no.

Answer (score 0):

There's an app that appears to serve this need (code *and* run a php server on an ipad): http://www.becomekodiak.com/kodiak-php.html